# Flask WSGI Apache: app doesn't find xlsx file

Tags: apache, flask, wsgi

My flask app loads an xlsx file from the directory where the app is stored. This works all fine when I use the flask server, but with apache I see an error in the log file saying:

```
"/app/rplods/thirdparty/apache/htdocs/dbshark/forms.py", line 18, in DroppdownForm, referer: http://xz.com:8000/
[Thu Jun 30 10:36:45.574793 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 4339:tid 140212003727104] [client 10.65.196.52:14532]     df = pd.read_excel(open('ldm.xlsx', 'rb'), sheetname='Sheet1'), referer: http://xz.com:8000/
[Thu Jun 30 10:36:45.574854 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 4339:tid 140212003727104] [client 10.65.196.52:14532] FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ldm.xlsx', referer: http://xz.com:8000/
```

Replacing the line as follows doesn't make any difference:

```
here=os.path.dirname(__file__)
g.df = pd.read_excel(open(os.path.join(here, 'ldm.xlsx'), 'rb'), sheetname='Sheet1')
```

Any suggestions are appreciated

Comment: What is in here? print(here)

Comment: .../apache/htdocs/flaskapp

Comment: forms.py is located at .../apache/htdocs/dbshark/ while "here" points to a different directory. Can this be the reason?

Comment: correction, here = ..../apache/htdocs/dbshark. I made sure it's the same folder. When I try to write a file I get permission denied error. Is this expected behavior or could it be connected to the above problem?

Comment: Could you try printing the result of os.path.join(here, 'ldm.xlsx') and then checking if the file is there? It might be that the Apache user has no permissions to access the file.

Comment: The path is correct. It must be connected to the Apache user. Where can I set up its permissions?